# Run script inside thankyou message HUBSPOT form

Tags: jquery, forms, rich-text-editor, hubspot

Apologies if this question is asked before, I'm new in HubSpot development.

I want to add a script inside Hubspot thank you for a message so that I will display another page after the delay of a few seconds,

```
setTimeout("window.location.href='redirecturl';",15000);
```

But, when I add this script inside the rich text[image], it displays the script tag like this.

However, I have tried it using adding an addition js file to the template but nothing is working.

Tried in the default way as well.

```
jQuery.getScript("//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js", function() {
    hbspt.forms.create({
        portalId: "protalid",
        formId: "formid",
        onFormSubmit: function($form) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "targeturl";
            }, 15000);
        }
    });
});
```

When I run `setTimeout("window.location.href='redirecturl';",15000);` this in the console then it is working but not using any file or adding it inside the rich text.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't actually embed a script in the thank you message. You would use the global form event callbacks in your page that's hosting the form and listen for the form submit there.

```
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
   if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
      setTimeout(function() {
         window.location = "targeturl";
      }, 15000);
   }
});
```